What is difference between "where column in ( select id from table)" and "where column = ( select id from table)" in terms of performance?
Suppose I want to fetch only latest date data from a table.
So, I write the below query.
Query 1:
select *
from tbl1
where dw_date = (select max(dw_date) from tbl)

Query 2:
select *
from tbl1
where dw_date in (select max(dw_date) from tbl)

Both queries will do the same thing.
But, I want to know which query will perform better on huge table.
Questions:

Does the inner subquery will run every time for each row of outer query?
Will the max(dw_date) will be calculated every time, irrespective of using dw_date in () and dw_date = ().

I tried using both the above query, and is giving me correct output.
I want to know how the query will perform, how it will work in backend.

Please tag only a single RDBMS... the one you want your answer in. You have tagged 4 completely different RDBMS!

And the answer is easily found out by trying this and inspecting the execution plan for the RDBMS you are using. Please do that, and then see if you have a question about the plan.

I don't believe this makes any noticeable difference, but just try out.

On a Postgres DB with one million rows in this table and without indices, both queries need about half a second, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0

I believe all databases are smart enough to know that max(dw_date) returns a single value and optimizes the query, so I strongly believe there is no difference between the performance of both queries. However, in general "=" is faster than "in". And the subquery will be executed only once!



Does the inner subquery run every time for each row of the outer query?


In both queries, the subquery SELECT MAX(dw_date) FROM tbl1 does not run for each row of the outer query. Most modern SQL databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and Oracle are optimized to calculate this only once for the entire query.
Backend Execution:
Single execution of subquery: The database calculates the MAX(dw_date) once, retrieves the result, and then applies the outer query's filter using that value. The optimizer ensures the subquery is not recalculated for every row in the outer table.
For example:
Subquery SELECT MAX(dw_date) FROM tbl1 will return 2023-09-03.
Then the outer query will check dw_date = '2023-09-03' for each row in tbl1.
